# sql joins - referencing a 3rd table but without duplicates

Tags: sql, join

I'm really not sure how to even phrase the question.  So I'll go by example.  I currently use this SQL command to get a total of all sales:

```
SELECT sum(ot.value*o.currency_value)
  FROM orders_total ot
  LEFT JOIN orders o on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id
 WHERE ot.class = 'ot_total'
   AND o.date_purchased between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31'
```

And that works fine, but now I want to do a report that cross-references the above with a 3rd table (orders_products) to sum up only the orders containing a specific product id.  So I tried this:

```
SELECT sum(ot.value*o.currency_value)
  FROM orders_total ot
 (LEFT JOIN orders o on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id)
  LEFT JOIN orders_products op on ot.orders_id = op.orders_id
 WHERE ot.class = 'ot_total'
   AND o.date_purchased between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31'
   AND op.products_id = 321
```

But that gives me a higher-than-expected total.  Investigating manually, I discovered the obvious reason is that any given order can (of course) have more than one product.

I'd like to show an example but I can't do tables here it seems.

Q: How do I sum up a total value without getting duplicate records from orders matching multiple entries in the op table?

Does that make any sense at all?

Edit:

I feel like I'm sort of onto something with this:

```
SELECT distinct o.orders_id
  FROM orders o
  JOIN orders_products op on o.orders_id = op.orders_id
 WHERE o.date_purchased between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31'
   AND op.products_id = 321
```

That results in a listing of all orders_id represented by the product in question.  So now I need to sort of inject that result into another statement summing up the values?  But how??

Edit:

Here's an attempt to show my tables:

#### orders_total

```
orders_total_id orders_id class      value 
--------------- --------- ---------- -------
    1                 1   ot_sub       100
    2                 1   ot_shipping  10
    3                 1   ot_total     110
    4                 2   ot_sub       200
    5                 2   ot_shipping  10
    6                 2   ot_total     210
    7                 3   ot_sub       50
    8                 3   ot_shipping  5
    9                 3   ot_sub       55
```

#### orders

```
orders_id    currency_value    date_purchased
---------    --------------    --------------
   1              1.0000         2010-04-20
   2              1.0000         2010-05-05
   3              1.0000         2010-06-01
```

#### orders_products

```
orders_products_id    orders_id    products_id
------------------    ---------    -----------
    1                     1            321
    2                     2            555
    3                     2            132
    4                     2            321
    5                     3            132
```

So I want an SQL statement that will give me a result of 320 (total of all orders containing product ID 321, which is orders 1 and 2 but not 3; "value" of "ot_total" for 1 is 110 and for 2 is 210.  110 + 210 = 320).

EDIT/SOLUTION:

Thanks to JNK for turning me on to EXISTS.  As it turns out, this did the job nicely:

```
SELECT sum(ot.value*o.currency_value) FROM orders_total ot LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.orders_id = ot.orders_id WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM orders_products op WHERE op.products_id = 321 AND op.orders_id = o.orders_id) and o.date_purchased between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31' and ot.class = 'ot_total'
```

Comment: We'll definitely need to see the DDL/diagram/definitions for those tables. What do you mean by "can't do tables here..."? I would suggest a quick look through other SQL questions for examples of table definitions and data samples formating.

Comment: ok, I see others using tables but I don't see how to do it. I'll figure something out and edit

Comment: Here's an exmaple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643370/sql-query-for-month-wise/5643435#5643435 It has one table instead of three. The formatting is just code. Enter some data, select it and then click the {} icon for code formatting. You can align it from there.

Comment: Order 2 has 3 items that total 210.  Where are the details to what each product cost?

Comment: There you go. FYI: I used Notepad++ and its column selection/.edit features to line things up nice and neat. It's all spaces w/o tabs which go haywire. Line breaks on your sample queries would be nice. You might also do well to dispense with unnecessary info. Present the tables' schema and the result you want with what you tried.

Comment: The `orders_total` table has two entries `ot_sub` and no entry `ot_total` for `orders_id = 3`.  Presumably, the entry with `orders_total_id = 9` should be `ot_total`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` - this is a perfect use case.

```
SELECT <all your fields>
FROM table
LEFT JOIN orders o
   ON table2.key = table.key
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM orders_products op
              WHERE op.products_id = xxx
              AND op.orderid = o.orderid)
```

This will do a short-circuit comparison on the subquery.  If the row in the outer query matches, it gets included.  If not, it's not in the final result set.

Comment: EXISTS is underrated. I love this implementation. Don't forget to alias/name the original table.

Comment: That's a correlated sub-query.  Unless the optimizer spots that it is and manages to rewrite the query to use a non-correlated sub-query, it is an expensive way of doing things.  Also, with EXISTS, it is convention to use '`SELECT *`' and it is not costly (or, if it is, get a better DBMS); the optimizer doesn't materialize the rows so the '*' really doesn't matter.

Comment: So how do you stop double counting for products that are in the same order?

Comment: Thanks!  EXISTS works.  I'm going to edit my question to include the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do it step by step, and don't use left outer join unless you really need to - you don't here.

1. List the orders which included product 321:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT Orders_ID
     FROM Orders_Products
    WHERE Products_ID = 321
   ```
2. List the component data for each relevant order:

   ```
   SELECT OT.Orders_ID, OT.Value, O.Currency_Value
     FROM Orders_Total AS OT
     JOIN Orders       AS O  ON OT.Orders_ID = O.Orders_ID
    WHERE O.Orders_ID IN
              (SELECT DISTINCT Orders_ID
                 FROM Orders_Products
                WHERE Products_ID = 321
              )
      AND OT.Class = 'ot_total'
      AND O.Date_Purchased BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'
   ```
3. Do the summation you want.

   ```
   SELECT SUM(OT.Value * O.Currency_Value) AS TotalOrderValue
     FROM Orders_Total AS OT
     JOIN Orders       AS O  ON OT.Orders_ID = O.Orders_ID
    WHERE O.Orders_ID IN
              (SELECT DISTINCT Orders_ID
                 FROM Orders_Products
                WHERE Products_ID = 321
              )
      AND OT.Class = 'ot_total'
      AND O.Date_Purchased BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'
   ```

There are other ways to write it - there almost always are many ways to write a query in SQL.  The DISTINCT is not really necessary in the sub-query.

As long as each order only has a single row in Orders_Products for any given Products_ID and you are only interested in the orders for a single part (not a list of parts), then you can modify the SQL into a more direct triple-join instead of using the sub-select:

```
SELECT SUM(OT.Value * O.Currency_Value) AS TotalOrderValue
  FROM Orders_Total    AS OT
  JOIN Orders          AS O  ON OT.Orders_ID = O.Orders_ID
  JOIN Orders_Products AS OP ON OP.Orders_ID = O.Orders_ID
 WHERE OP.Products_ID = 321
   AND OT.Class = 'ot_total'
   AND O.Date_Purchased BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'
```

However, if you need to select the values for orders containing any of a list of parts or other changes, then you're likely to find that the sub-query notation is easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response.  While much longer, this method is easier to understand WHY it works so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to me where the details that go into orders_total.value live in your tables?  Usually you have something like:

```
select sum(op.qty*op.price) as Total
from orders o 
JOIN orders_products op on o.orders_id = op.orders_id 
where o.date_purchased between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31 23:59' 
and op.products_id = 321
```

Or a full report like:

```
select p.ProductName, totals.Total
from (
    select op.products_id, sum(op.qty*op.price) as Total
    from orders o 
    join orders_products op on o.orders_id = op.orders_id 
    where o.date_purchased between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31 23:59' 
    group by op.products_id) totals
join Products p
on totals.products_id = p.products_id
```

Comment: Problem is that products_id is in one table, value is in a 2nd, while currency value is in a 3rd.

Comment: No, the problem is you don't have the totals.value broken down by product anywhere? So for order 2 how do I know what part of the total belongs to product 555 vs. 132?

Comment: @Steven: further to what JBrooks says, normally you can order 10 of one part and 20 of another; where do you keep a record of the number of the item order.  Normally, you also have a table of parts identifying valid part numbers and the list price (and usually a lot of other information too).  Your schema is at best unusual.

Comment: @both of you... I thought it was rather obvious that I was giving the bare minimum schema for my example.  The real tables are far more complex but I didn't think it made sense to have you weed through all the unrelated specifics.