# Sql query for month wise

Tags: sql-server

I was trying on a sql query where we have search on month wise

for example my table is like

```
Username   visited  Visisted_Dated

   A          1       01/11/2010
   B          1       10/11/2010
   A          1       03/12/2010
   B          1       06/12/2010
   B          1       06/12/2010
   A          1       03/02/2011 
   B          1       05/02/2011
   A          1       11/03/2011
   A          1       20/03/2011
   B          1       01/03/2011
```

Now if i want to search the users for no of visited between Feb to April i need to get output as

```
 Users Nov_2010  Dec_2010   Jan_2011   Feb_2011  March_2011 
   A       1         1        0           1           2               
   B       1         2        0           1           1
```

Please let me know the way to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that you want more columns as you get more months?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you have to make use of dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @BeginDate = '2010-11-1'
SET @EndDate = '2011-4-1'
SET @ColumnNames = ''

WHILE @BeginDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnNames = @ColumnNames + ',[' + DateName(month,@BeginDate) + '_' + Cast(Year(@BeginDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'
    SET @BeginDate = DateAdd(Month, 1, @BeginDate)
END
IF Len(@ColumnNames) > 0
    SET @ColumnNames = Right(@ColumnNames, Len(@ColumnNames) - 1)

PRINT @ColumnNames

SET @Sql = '
WITH U AS
(
    SELECT UserName, DateName(month,Visited_Dated) + ''_'' + Cast(Year(Visited_Dated) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS VisitedMonth, Visited
    FROM Users
)
SELECT *
FROM U
PIVOT (
    SUM(Visited) FOR VisitedMonth IN (' + @ColumnNames + ')
) AS P'

EXEC (@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

There it´s a solution based on `PIVOT`

```
SELECT UserName,[201011], [201012], [201101], [201102], [201103]
FROM
(SELECT UserName,Visited,convert(varchar(6),[Visited_Dated],112) Periodo
FROM [Table]) AS st
PIVOT
(
COUNT(Visited)
FOR Periodo IN ([201011], [201012], [201101], [201102], [201103])
) AS pt;
```